# Openssl stucks on SSL_library_init() when compiled on FreeBSD (clang9 and clang11) when using -fsanitize=address

Tags: clang, llvm, freebsd, sanitize

I am getting my software stuck when starting Openssl on **FreeBSD 13** (OpenSSL 1.1.1k-freebsd  25 Mar 2021) when using **-fsanitize=address** in **clang11**, same problem happens with **clang9**.

The problem happens indistinctly with:

- OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
- SSL_library_init()
- SSL_load_error_strings();

To reproduce the problem:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SSL_library_init();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then compile and execute:

```
clang  -lssl -lcrypto -fsanitize=address -o test test.c && ./test
```

Compilation happens fine but the program stuck on **SSL_library_init()** using **100% of CPU**. Once the **-fsanitize=address** is **removed** everything works as expected.

Comment: You're encountering this bug: https://reviews.llvm.org/D84509 - ssl is calling qsort, which is broken when run with the address sanitizer. I do not have the search-fu to know when it gets fixed.

Comment: Did nobody after all this time realized there was a problem with LLVM9-LLVM11 and SSL?, did nobody on the world compiled with sanitize until now? Am I that lucky?

Comment: I can confirm the problem also happens in LLVM12.

Comment: @Petesh the bug that you report seems been fixed on 1 sept 2020 ( https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/46176 ) so I am not sure we are pointing at the same bug. LLVM12 was released on 8 july 2021 and the problem also happens with LLVM12. In the other hand the behaviour is exactly as described in that bug.

Comment: This seems to be resolved already in the FreeBSD side: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/46176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the solution by the OP to the Answer area.

I backtraced the bug and this is not an OpenSSL bug, I have confirmed this is a LLVM bug as pointed in the comments:

````
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000027ffa7 in wrapped_qsort_compar (a=0x80087ed60, b=0x80087eef0)
    at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:9741
#1  0x0000000800d6e974 in qsort () from /lib/libc.so.7
#2  0x0000000000280083 in __interceptor_qsort (base=<optimized out>, nmemb=44, size=80, 
    compar=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:9761
#3  0x0000000800d6f846 in qsort () from /lib/libc.so.7
#4  0x0000000000280083 in __interceptor_qsort (base=<optimized out>, nmemb=164, size=80, 
    compar=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/contrib/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:9761
#5  0x000000080082b6af in ?? () from /usr/lib/libssl.so.111
#6  0x000000080083120e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libssl.so.111
#7  0x0000000800835f39 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libssl.so.111
#8  0x0000000800b8fe23 in pthread_once () from /lib/libthr.so.3
#9  0x00000008009a1019 in CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once () from /lib/libcrypto.so.111
#10 0x0000000800835ce2 in OPENSSL_init_ssl () from /usr/lib/libssl.so.111
#11 0x00000000002b37a9 in main ()
(gdb) 
```
````